# Extend lambda expression with sub lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I'm trying to figure out if it is at all possible to combine 2 LambdaExpressions, where one lambda expression uses a Child property of the first.

Given the following 2 classes:

```
class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SubClass Child { get; set; }
}

class SubClass
{
    public string SubClassName { get; set; }
}
```

And the following expressions:

```
Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> Expression1 = c => c.Name == "Test";

Expression<Func<SubClass, bool>> Expression2 = sc => sc.SubClassName == "SubTest";
```

I'd like to combine it to a lambda of the following type:

```
Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> Combined;
```

Reason being: The upper lambda is internal, and the lower lamba would be passed in by the 'user' of the method, which has no idea (nor should he) that MyClass exists, has only knowledge of SubClass.

Is this at all possible, or should I find another road to follow?

Comment: How is it possible they won't know about your class, the resulting lambda would have to look like x.Child.SubClassName == "SubTest" because you'd have to navigate from MyClass

Comment: Find(Expression<Func<SubClass, bool>>), that's what will be exposed

Comment: However internally, I need it in the form of Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>>

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it's exactly what you're after, but;

```
public class Search
{
    private IEnumerable<MyClass> _data;

    public Search(IEnumerable<MyClass> data)
    {
        _data = data;
    }

    public IEnumerable<MyClass> Find(Expression<Func<SubClass, bool>> expr)
    {
        ParameterExpression x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyClass), "x");
        PropertyInfo p = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("Child");

        var propertyExpression = (expr.Body as BinaryExpression).Left as MemberExpression;
        var constant = (expr.Body as BinaryExpression).Right;

        var memberAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(x, p);
        var upperMemberAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(memberAccess, propertyExpression.Member);

        var equals = Expression.Equal(upperMemberAccess, constant);

        var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyClass, bool>>(equals, x);

        return _data.Where(expression.Compile());
    }
}
```

And then using it looks like this;

```
var search = new Search(new[] {
        new MyClass { Name = "Test 1", Child = new SubClass { SubClassName = "Bob" }},
        new MyClass { Name = "Test 2", Child = new SubClass { SubClassName = "Subclass"}},
        new MyClass { Name = "Test 3", Child = new SubClass { SubClassName = "Subclass"}}
    });

    search.Find(k => k.SubClassName == "Subclass");
```

I'm certain there is a better way of doing this, as this feels clunky, but basically it will find all members of MyClass that have a subclass with the name 'Subclass'. It extracts the components of the binary expression handed (x => x.SubClassname == "Subclass" ), and rebuilds a new expression with equals based of MyClass.